# Dúvida ao usar TimerTask

Tags: java, timer, task

segue meu exemplo de uso da classe `TimerTask` e meu problema é o seguinte: 
  Eu quero fazer com que todo dia as 12 horas seja feita essa rotina automaticamente. Atualmente não está acontecendo nada, será que esta faltando algo? E essa classe basta só dar um deploy no tomcat que funciona sem instanciá-la?

```
public class PausarTempo{

//INTERVALO DE TEMPO EM MILESEGUNDOS REFERENTE A 24 HORAS
public static final long TEMPO = (1000*60*60*20); 

public void pararTempo(){
//definindo a hora qua a tarefa sera executada pela primeira vez
   Calendar dataHoraInicio = Calendar.getInstance();
   dataHoraInicio.set(Calendar.HOUR_OFDAY,12); 
   dataHoraInicio.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
   dataHoraInicio.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

Timer timer = null;
    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Començando...");
                   // MINHA REGRA
                    System.out.println("Fim.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, dataHoraInicio.geteTime(), TEMPO);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário realizar a primeira chamada do método, depois disso, acredito que fica uma `thread` rodando, na espera dos periodos do tempo que foi setado.

Ao testar pelo método `main`, funciona normalmente, acredito que essa lógica para o primeiro delay, não funcionou, poís o delay também é preciso ser em `milisegundos`. `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

Portanto caso precisar do tempo em [milisegundos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) da API Calendar, chame o método `getTimeInMillis`

```
public class PausarTempo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pararTempo();
    }

    public static final long PERIODO_TEMPO = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 20);

    public static void pararTempo() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Començando...");
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, 0, 5000); //Troque para PERIODO_TEMPO
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: entendi Douglas, então para funcionar eu vou ter que ativar o método uma unica vez. Em relação ao "getTime()" ele funcionou de boa. Vou testar aqui  no ambiente de produção e ativar o método manual e jaja posto se funcionou, vlws.

Comment: No ambiente de produção ta ok tbm. Tópico fechado vlw